# Difference between traditional constructor alternate constructor inflating layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I'm learning Android developing with Kotlin.
I have a question for inflating a layout.

I can use two ways. The traditional way:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

The alternative way:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

My question: is there any difference of usage? I mean is there a casa where I have to use one over the other, or are they operating the same, only written in a different way?
If there is an difference, which one and when I have to prefer the traditional and when the alternative method on inflating?
Maybe if there is any article or something it will be appreciated if someone can post me a link to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, inside `onCreateView` (notice the different override) is where you'd usually do the following:

```
  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.foo, container, false)
}
```

Since this is where we're *creating* the view, it makes sense to leave it like that, right ?

now, inside `onViewCreated` :

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is `onCreateView` not `onViewCreated`, and there is no difference as you can look at the code of Fragment `onCreateView`, if there is `layout_id` provided in constructor, `onCreate` will `inflate` and return it for you

```
  @Nullable
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
       @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         if (mContentLayoutId != 0) {
            return inflater.inflate(mContentLayoutId, container, false);
         }
         return null;
    }
```